# Replace hyphen between two letters, but not bewteen two numbers (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I know you can do this to replace any "hyphen" symbol:

```
$tmp = str_replace("-", " ", $tmp);
```

but that also replaces any minus signs too (which I would like to retain).

Using regular expressions to only get a hyphen between two letters:

```
$tmp = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]/", " ", $tmp);
```

replaces the hyphen, but also the letter on each side of it, with a space.

Is there an elegant way to get just a hyphen between two letters and not between two numbers?

Comment: `preg_replace("/([a-z])-([a-z])/i", "$1$2", $tmp);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use look-around [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
$tmp = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $tmp);
```

The `(?<=[a-z])` asserts the presence of a letter preceding the dash; the `(?=[a-z])` does the same thing following the dash.

Assertions are not memory captures so they're not affected when doing a replacement.

Comment: Lookarounds seem to be the fastest approach because hyphen are rare in the sample data. https://3v4l.org/fJM4N